# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'already known'}

Tags: web3.py

I am performing a transaction to send an ERC20 and I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'already known'}
```

I'm assuming this means that this transaction is already in the mempool or something? Looking for some clarifications though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer...

> I'm assuming this means that this transaction is already in the mempool or something?

Yes. From [`tx_pool.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d8ff53dfb8a516f47db37dbc7fd7ad18a1e8a125/core/tx_pool.go#L57):

```
// ErrAlreadyKnown is returned if the transactions is already contained
// within the pool.
ErrAlreadyKnown = errors.New("already known")
```

But it's not immediately clear from the code what conditions have to be met for this error to be set, so it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: I think this is pretty much it. Just wanted others to be aware of what is going on when they run into this error.

Comment: I think the nonce can be used to prevent the error, and it needs to be checked against the most recent older nonce.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error using *github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum*

First, make sure you are using the right nonce in the tx

```
nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context, someAddress)
```

Then, make sure you are passing the right context to all your methods, including the one above